# How to securely store free text users answers

Tags: mysql, database, encryption, mobile, freetext

We are creating 3 different questionnaires in our iOS and Android apps. The users have to answer questions with free text. Most of the information is medical sensitive data. After completing the questionnaire the user should have the option to download his/her answers into a pdf and save answers which they can view when they open one of the questionnaires. We are using MYSQL to store data into our server.

What is the best way to encrypt the user text data on our server?

Should we store the answers on the users' phones?

Comment: Do you have $5000 a year to spend on the MySQL that will do it automatically

Comment: Your question is possibly too broad.  MySQL itself might be able to encrypt a column or table.  If not, then you would have to encrypt the text in the application layer (e.g. Java, C#, PHP, etc.) using something like AES.  As for generating the PDFs, that wouldn't necessarily have anything to do with encryption.